# GPU has 2 PCIE and my power supply only has one PCIE

Tags: power-supply, gpu

when I finished putting together my pc I saw that my GPU had 2 PCIe and that my power supply had 1 just wondering if it is a problem and my GPU is a 1070 galax and PSU is corsair cx450

Comment: A 450W psu is very likely NOT sufficient to power your GPU.

Answer (score 2):

Your GPU might not be able to draw enough power which can lead to a manifold of different problems, but I think the worst case scenario is, that it just shuts down. In that case it's time for a more potent PSU (which should at least be able to provide 500W)

Comment: I'd back that up by saying [nvidia's minimum recommendation's 500W](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-1070/specifications).

Answer (score 2):

Most power supplies should come with a sata to PCI-e converter, or you can purchase and use one for the second PCIe power input. *However* nvidia [recommends a minimum of 500W](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-1070/specifications) for a 1070